# Which of these choices is the better design for drawing objects?

Tags: performance, drawing, xna

What would be a better parctice, writing the drawing method inside the GameObject class or in the Game class?

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject();
obj.Draw();
```

Or

```
GameObject obj = new GameObject();
DrawGameObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `Game` and `GameObject` are responsible for. Typically, a `GameObject` would contain all the information about *what* to draw -- it'd have a model, for instance. But objects aren't independent of each other -- knowing *what* to draw isn't sufficient to know *how* to draw it.

So a `Game` probably knows a lot more than a `GameObject`. In particular, it might know:

- whether or not a particular object *should* be drawn (e.g. it's occluded based on the current camera)
- *how* to draw a particular object (shadows from other objects; reflections from nearby surfaces; ambient light factors; etc.)
- etc.

Of the two options presented, it probably makes more sense to put the `Draw` method outside the `GameObject`.

Comment: Thank you, great comment, and thanks about the edit, didn't know how to express my question.  Is there any performance difference?

Comment: It's probably _worse_ performance to put `Draw` on `GameObject`, because then each `GameObject` would have to know about all the others, while a `Game` can probably be smarter and resolve all these interactions more succinctly.

Comment: Also, if you're building an object graph of items to draw and need to only draw game objects that would be visible on screen, the game object manager would be the one to call draw on each of your game objects.

Your second option implies the game object itself knows when to draw itself, which is outside of it's responsibility.